# Python print result several variables/function calls on same line with string

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the result of a function call concat a string and another result of a function call.

More specifically:

time stamp and a socket peer name (IP address)...

I can't figure out how python syntax works. I've been trying different version but in essence what i've tried is something like this:

```
print time.strftime("%X") " - " socket.getpeername()
```

I want to print "time - IP address" from clients connecting to the server...

How can I print two "variables" or rather the result of a function calls with a string in between, in my case a hyphen(-).

any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
now  = time.strftime("%X")
peer = socket.getpeername()
print("{} - {}".format(now, peer))
```

Comment: Note that `{}` only works with 2.7 or later.

Comment: This didnt work for me... I've got Python 2.7.3

Comment: Oh wait  second! it did work... thanks alot for that Python is really complicated but powerfull! I am going to do some starters guide/tutorial... Thanks again...

Answer (score 2):

```
print ' - '.join(
      map(str, [time.strftime("%X"), socket.getpeername()])
)
```

The `map` expression is converting each of the arguments to a string.

The `join` method is interspersing `' - '` between the two strings.